# Using Spring MVC 3.0 and @EJB annotation wtihout mappedName?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, ejb

I am making a new Java webapp with Spring MVC 3.0 and want to use as much standard Java EE 6  stuff as I can.  (I'm on Glassfish 3.1.1.)  The real driver is wanting to use an MVC web framework rather than JSF.

So I'm looking for the best way to inject EJBs into my Spring controllers.  I had some success but I'm not happy with how it looks and I was hoping to find a better way.

This worked, by finding the EJB via JNDI:

```
// EJB 
@Stateless
public class Service {
  @PersistenceContext(name="MAIN")
  private EntityManager em;

  public void doSomething() { .... } 

}

// Spring 
@Controller
public class HomeController {
   @EJB(mappedName="java:global/springtest/Service") 
   private Service service;

   // controller methods use service 
}
```

But I'm unhappy with needing the "mappedName" on the @EJB annotation in the controller.

Is there a better way to do this?

The good news, though, is that I can use the same @Inject annotation in EJBs and Spring beans and the only difference is which framework is creating the object and doing the injection.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
mappedName="java:module/Service"
```

instead of

```
mappedName="java:global/springtest/Service"
```

you do not have to worry about the appname. 
This makes the code more portable. I guess that will solve some of your problems

Answer (score -1):

For Spring, you could wrap the JNDI lookup into `JndiObjectFactoryBean`:

```xml
<bean id="serviceBean" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:global/springtest/Service" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Then you'll *probably* (correct me if I'm wrong) be able to use it with `@Inject` *without* the `@Named("serviceBean")` annotation:

```
@Inject
private Service service;
```

Comment: That just pushes the problem to XML, which feels worse IMO.

Comment: @wrschneider99 Why? You wanted to get rid of the *mappedName* parameter and so you got it. Was not that the question? Otherwise you could do the JNDI lookup in the code and that would be fully portable, but ugly.

Comment: I was hoping that there was some way that the JNDI lookup  could happen by convention, such that an explicit mappedName was unnecessary.  Or if necessary I wouldn't mind pushing the configuration to the Stateless annotation, to take advantage of any defaults inherent to Spring's interpretation of the EJB annotation.